# How to set java flags when launching a jar from the OS X GUI?

Tags: java, jar, osx-snow-leopard

I want the flag "-Xmx1g" to be set when i click on a particular jar file in OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the flag "-Xmx1g" to be set when i click on a particular jar
>   file in OS X.

You can't. By clicking the JAR file, OS X will choose the default application for running .jar files. Which is of course `java` (which is called Jar Launcher in OS X).

What you can do is wrap the JAR into an executable. [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) is nice to do this.
Second option is to write a shell script (bash, but with the `.command` file extension) that invokes your jar using that flag.

Comment: I was trying to avoid Lanuch4j but thanks for the shell script idea.